# Increasing length of x asis in GGplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hi I have made a plot with Chromosomes on x axis and P values on y-axis. On x axis I get all 20 chromosomes that were in the analysis but I want the x axis size to increase to 23 total.

```
ggplot(Results, aes(x = factor(Chromosomes), y = P-value)) + 
geom_point() + 
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90) +  xlab("Chromosome")+ ylab("P-value") +labs(title= 
"Results_analysis" ,y="P-value", x = "Chromosomes")
```

regards

Answer (score 0):

All you need is `xlim()`. For example:

```
library(ggplot2)
p = ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = hp)) +
        geom_point()
p
```

[image]

Here we increase the x-axis limit:

```
p + xlim(10, 55)
```

[image]

Therefore, adding `xlim(0, 35)` to your `ggplot` will do the trick.

Comment: Hi but I want the values on x axis to be continuous like 10, 11 ,12 ,13.....50 or as in my example from 1,2,3,4,5,6,7....23

Comment: @Khan_16 can you please share some reproducible data? in  case you dont know how to do it - use `dput(your_data)` or subset of it. For more information run `?dput` in your console :)